# how to override the existing function in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascriptmvc

This is default for all js

```
getEditor: function(){
    $( '#datatableEditor' ).remove();
    var editor = $( '<div id="datatableEditor" class="popupEditor"/>' );
    $( 'body' ).prepend( editor );

    var dialog = $(editor).dialog({
        title: 'Edit item',
        modal: true,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto'
    });
```

Now I am writing another js. I need to override the `getEditor` in my js...

Comment: what you want to change / implement

Comment: i need to change the title. it is same for all but i need to change title as action name

Answer (score 10):

You haven't described your question, clearly but based on what you have mentioned in the title:

> override the existing function in jquery

It seems you want to change a jQuery function and they usually are defined like `$.fn.getEditor` if it is the case, you should do:

```
(function ($) {
    var oldGetEditor = $.fn.getEditor;
    $.fn.getEditor = function() {

       //you can call the oldGetEditor here if you want
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply get a reference to the function "getEditor" and assign it another function.

```
getEditor:function(){
// new function will override the existing reference that getEditor already has.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
someObject = {
 getEditor: function(){
  $( '#datatableEditor' ).remove();
  var editor = $( '<div id="datatableEditor" class="popupEditor"/>' );
  $( 'body' ).prepend( editor );

  var dialog = $(editor).dialog({
    title: 'Edit item',
    modal: true,
    width: 'auto',
    height: 'auto'
  });
}
```

So just write

```
someObject.getEditor = function(){
  // your own logic here
}
```

You must get object where getEditor function stored, and use reference to change it.